# How to auto-format lines in Libre Office Writer

Tags: libreoffice-writer, comments, autocorrect

I would like to see all the lines starting with '//' in a grey colour (Like comments in an IDE). Can I do this automatically while typing using the autocorrect feature any other feature available in Libre Office Writer?

I tried to use replace in auto-currect options. I was able to replace strings starting with prefix '//' to some predefined text. I don't want to replace the whole text. I just want to format lines that start with '//'.
Can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
2. Find what: `^//.*$`
3. Replace with: `$0`.
4. Click Format -> Font Effects -> Font Color. Select your color. Click OK
5. Tick Regular expression.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BInFS.png)

6. Click Replace All

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works great!. Can this be done automatically while typing?

Comment: @mig001 Not sure if it can be done while tyoing.